# Identity Toolkit API has not been used in project before or it is disabled

Tags: android, firebase, authentication

I'm trying to create phone number account using Firebase in Android project. I have added Firebase using the Android Studio's Firebase Assistant.

but i have problem

**An internal error has occurred. [ Identity Toolkit API has not been used in project before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/overview?project= then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.**

i am trying create toolkit api but not working. i dont understant what is wrong ?

Comment: how you solved this

Comment: You solved this?

Answer (score 1):

The link that you have been provided for Google Developer Console not Firebase You have to enable authentication from Firebase console from this link
[Firebase developer Console](https://console.firebase.google.com)

[image: step 1]

and then choose the auth type you need from follow:
[image: step 2]